# Export sqlite3 table to csv or txt file with python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, sqlite

i know this question has already been answered but reading:([Sqlite3 / python - Export from sqlite to csv text file does not exceed 20k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556450/sqlite3-python-export-from-sqlite-to-csv-text-file-does-not-exceed-20k))
I didnt understand it cause i now very little from python and i know very little english so could please someone explain how to do it for a newbie?

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17557103/103081) has 5 lines of python code.  Please explain: what lines of python code in answer do you not understand?

Comment: everything, i dont undestand a thing there

Comment: Then it would probably be useful to attempt to understand those 5 lines there. We can't read code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the code i've done so far, its very simple and works well:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Column 1', 'Column 2', ...])
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Thanks to @Dougal from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522830/how-to-export-sqlite-to-csv-in-python-without-being-formatted-as-a-list)