# Join csv to sqlite database using python

Tags: python, sqlite, join, csv

I have a sqlite-database table with 3 three columns (X,Y,Z).
Additionally I have a csv file (with header) having 10 columns
but also the same X and Y. I'd like to join the the csv file
to the database table using a python script.

So far I managed to establish the db-connection and to create
the new columns in the database like:

```
import csv, sqlite3
database = sqlite3.connect("my_sqlitedatabase")
db = database.cursor()
db.execute("ALTER TABLE dbtable ADD COLUMN 'col1' float")
db.execute("ALTER TABLE dbtable ADD COLUMN 'col2' float")
db.execute("ALTER TABLE dbtable ADD COLUMN 'col3' float")
```

So far I haven't found anything to use .import in python instead
I probably need to read in the csv file directly (see [Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python))

```
csvtable = csv.reader(open('csvtable.txt', 'r'), delimiter=',')
```

For joining I'd like to use something like:

```
UPDATE dbtable SET csvtable_col1=(SELECT dbtable.col1 FROM csvtable AS c 
... WHERE csvtable.X=dbtable.X AND csvtable.Y=dbtable.Y)
```

How can I join the csv table to my database table using pyhton? The both
share X and Y as common columns and a combination of both can be used as unique
key for joining. Both tables have several 100000 rows. Do I need to loop over
the rows of csv file? Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to create a table in your SQLite3 database for the CVS data and insert the rows from the file there. Then you'll be able to perform queries joining the two tables.

Comment: Yes either you can loop over rows of csv in python and insert. Or you can follow @PedroRomano 's suggestion. You probably can't do it the way you want.

Comment: I think I'll go for importing the data from csv to sqlite and then joining them afterwards... Thanks