# CSV files - merging, if column with same value do:

Tags: python, csv, awk

I'm working on the integration of 2 CSV files.

Files are made by the following columns:

First .csv:

```
SKU | Name | Quantity | Active
121 | Jablko | 23 | 1
```

Another .csv consists following:

```
SKU | Quantity
232 | 4
121 | 2
```

I'd like to update 1.csv with data from 2.csv, in Linux, any idea how to do it in best way? Python?

Comment: Are there really spaces around the separators, and are the separators really `|`s?

Comment: Import both tables in a DB then query using a join.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python

Comment: 1 CSV file is generated by the warehouse sytem, another one is generated from the website/shop/database, thats impossible to do this in MySQL

Separator is ','

Comment: For parsing, combining, and analyzing real-world data, I switched to Python [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/#quick-vignette) from SQL. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The awk solution:

```
awk -F ' \\| ' -v OFS=' | ' '
    NR == FNR {val[$1] = $2; next}
    $1 in val {$3 = val[$1]} 
    {print}
' 2.csv 1.csv
```

The `FS` input field separator variable is treated as a regular expression while the output field separator is treated as a plain string, hence the different treatement of the pipe character.

Comment: I believe you meant to write `$1 in val`. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with gnu awk (`awk -f script.awk file2.csv file1.csv`):

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
FNR == NR {
     upd[$1] = $2
     next
}

{$3 = upd[$1]; print}
```

Comment: This would make pipe delimited file to space delimited one.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something along the lines of:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('first.csv') as f1, open('second.csv') as f2, open('new', 'wb') as fout:
    sku_to_qty = dict(islice(csv.reader(f2, delimiter='|'), 1, None)) # create lookup table
    csvin = csv.reader(f1, delimiter='|') # input
    csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|') # output
    csvout.writerow(next(csvin)) # write header
    for row in csvin:
        row[2] = sku_to_qty.get(row[0], row[2]) # update or presume the same
        csvout.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$3=a[$1]" "}1' second.csv first.csv
```