# Pickled 3D array is larger than it should be. How do I fix this?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, numpy, pickle

I am pickling a 1544 x 1936 x 256 array of 2 byte integers created by `numpy.zeros((1544,1936,256),dtype='int16')` which logically should take up ~1.5 GB of memory and did when I used to run this program on windows. Recently I moved to Ubuntu and when I run this command the resulting file is 6.1 GB. Why is the resulting file nearly 4x bigger than expected on linux?

Comment: You should use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` instead, it will keep you much closer to the "expected" size. Pickle is actually a transformation of the data, so there is no expectation of maintaining the native data size.

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253976/pickling-pandas-dataframe-does-multiply-by-5-the-file-size

Comment: `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` instead, it will keep you much closer to the "expected" size. Pickle is actually a transformation of the data, so there is no expectation of maintaining the native data size.

See for example: [stackoverflow.com/questions/30253976/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253976/pickling-pandas-dataframe-does-multiply-by-5-the-file-size) – Benjamin