# copy csv file into sqlite database table using python

Tags: python, sqlite

There is a post that tells me how to write data fom a csv-file into a sqlite database ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python)). **Is there a way to simply copy the whole file into a database table** instead of loading the data and then iterate through the rows appending them to the table as suggested in the link.

To do this in sqlite it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python) to simply type

```
sqlite> create table test (id integer, datatype_id integer, level integer, meaning text);
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import no_yes.csv test
```

I am new to working with databases and sqlite3, but I thought doing something like this could work

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table(name):
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (time REAL, event INTEGER, id INTEGER, size INTERGER, direction INTEGER)".format(name))

def copy_data(file2copy,table_name):
    c.executescript("""    
    .separator ","    
    .import {} {}""".format(file2copy,table_name))
    conn.commit()


try:
    create_table('abc')
    copy_data(r'Y:\MYPATH\somedata.csv','abc')

except Exception as e:
    print e

c.close()
conn.close()
```

But apparently it doesn't. I get the error

```
near ".": syntax error
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to the below suggestion to use the subprocess module, I came up with the follwing solution.

```
import subprocess

sqlshell = r'c:\sqlite-tools\sqlite3' # sqlite3.exe is a shell that can be obtained from the sqlite website
process = subprocess.Popen([sqlshell], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

cmd = """.open {db}
.seperator ","
.import {csv} {tb}""".format(db='C:/Path/to/database.db', csv='C:/Path/to/file.csv', tb='table_name')

stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=cmd)

if len(stderr):
    print 'something went wrong'
```

Importantly, you should use '/' instead of '\' in your directory names. Also, you have to be carefull with blank spaces in your directory names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands you're using in `copy_data` that start with `.` are not part of `sqlite3`, but the interactive shell that it ships with it. You can't use them through the `sqlite3` module.

You either need to manually write the insertion step or use the `subprocess` module to run the shell program.