# Python import CSV short code (pandas?) delimited with ';' and ',' in entires

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, separator

I need to import a CSV file in Python on Windows. My file is delimited by ';' and has strings with non-English symbols and commas (',').

I've read posts:

[Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python)

[Python import csv to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list)

When I run:

```
with open('d:/trade/test.csv', 'r') as f1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    your_list1 = list(reader1)
```

I get an issue: comma is changed to '-' symbol.

When I try:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csvfile)
```

I got errors:

> pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2.

Please help. I would prefer to use pandas as the code is shorter without listing all field names from the CSV file.

I understand there could be the work around of temporarily replacing commas. Still, I would like to solve it by some parameters to pandas.

Comment: Can we see a small snippet of your CSV data that produces the problem?

Comment: `reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=';')` - try that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Pandas** solution - use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with regex separator `[;,]`. You need add `engine='python'`, because warning:

> ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""a;b;c
1;1,8
1;2,1
1;3,6
1;4,3
1;5,7
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="[;,]", engine='python')
print (df)

   a  b  c
0  1  1  8
1  1  2  1
2  1  3  6
3  1  4  3
4  1  5  7
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas documentation says for parameters:

[pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
sep : str, default ‘,’

    Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this.
```

Pandas did not parse my file delimited by `;` because default is not `None` denoted for automatic but `,`. Adding `sep` parameter set to `;` for `pandas` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your CSV file is broken, you can try to make `csv` guess your format.

```
import csv

with open('d:/trade/test.csv', 'r') as f1:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024))
    f1.seek(0)
    r = csv.reader(f1, dialect=dialect)
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the encoding, you will need to find out what is the encoding of file one is trying to read.

I have used ASCII for this example, but it could be different.

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, encoding='ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid below warning in your code,

> ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'

Use property names inside of your `read_csv` function. Check the example for both cases where this warning comes and where it won't.

CODE THAT THROW WARNING:

```py
selEncoding = "ISO-8859–1"

dfCovid19DS = pd.read_csv(dsSrcPath, selEncoding)
```

CODE WITHOUT WARNING:

```py
selEncoding = "ISO-8859–1"

dfCovid19DS = pd.read_csv(dsSrcPath, encoding = selEncoding)
```

Comment: Credit where due: This is essentially the same answer as @Santosh-Pathak gave two years ago ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459498/3025856)).