# Python Script to Delete Data from SQLite DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to python and SQLite, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.  I've written the code below to open up a database and delete the data in the STAGING_LIDs table.  The script runs, but when I check the DB, the data is still there.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\SQLite\\Budget_Dev.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

#delete all table data
cur.execute("DELETE FROM STAGING_LIDs;")
```

I'm using bernie's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python) question (the accepted answer) as a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to add a line:

```
conn.commit()
```