# Import a dictionary from a .dat file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a .txt file with a list of countries and that countries information separated by commas. My problem is to use that file to create a dictionary, then save that dictionary to a pickled .dat file, and finally import that dictionary so the user can search a countries name and print the information.

I think I created the dictionary and saved it to the dat file correctly, I am having trouble importing the dictionary and searching through it.
This is my code for creating and saving the dictionary:

```
    natDict = {}
with open("UN.txt","r") as filestream:
    for line in filestream:
        currentLine = line.split(",")
        newC = Nation(currentLine[0],currentLine[1],float(currentLine[2]),float(currentLine[3])) #creats new Nation object
        natDict[currentLine[0]] = newC

with open('nationsDict.dat', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(natDict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Now I have to create a new program that uses the nationsDict.dat file so the user can search for countries. I don't have any experience with pickled dat files and my teacher's lecture slides don't say anything about them. I am guessing I have to import the dat file and then make it a dictionary again so that the user can search it, I just don't know how I am supposed to do it.

//Edit
Sorry that the question is a bit unclear, I'll try and give more info.
I created an object for each Nation so that the dictionary is like {CountryName: CountryObject}.

```
class Nation:
def __init__(self, name, cont, pop, area):
    self.name = name
    self.cont = cont
    self.pop = pop
    self.area = area
    self.popDens = self.calcPopDensity(pop,area)

def calcPopDensity(self,pop,area):
    return((pop * 1000000) / area)

def __str__(self):
    return (self.name + ":\ncontinent: " + self.cont + "\npopulation: " + str(self.pop) +
            " million \narea: " + str(self.area) + "\nPopulation Density : " + str(self.popDens))
```

The UN.txt file is setup like:
Afghanistan,Asia,31.8,251772
Albania,Europe,3.0,11100
Algeria,Africa,38.3,919595
Andorra,Europe,.085,181
Angola,Africa,19.1,481354

With all nations in the UN in the file.

All I really need to know is how I can use the nationsDict.dat file to search items. I put a dictionary in it, so could I just import it and use it like it is still a dictionary? Or do I have to create a dictionary again with the information in the .data file.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This problem could be solved with Python dicts, but since SQLite is built in, you might find it easier to use that. There's a fairly simple example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you open your `.dat` file, import your data (with `pickle.load` method) into your variables. You will also want to import (with `import`) your `Nation` class into the new program or you will get errors.

Edit:
You can just save your objects, calling `pickle.dump` method with each one of the objects at a time, and then load them also one at a time. `pickle` will handle the types for you. But if you are loading a type of your own (defined with `class`) the source code for the class has to be available, thus the errors if it's not, and the need to import those classes into the loading script.

See a simple example and explanation here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure I am not, that is why someone downvoted your question :)