# Load existing db file to memory Python sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an existing sqlite db file, on which I need to make some extensive calculations. Doing the calculations from the file is painfully slow, and as the file is not large (~10 MB), so there should be no problem to load it into memory.

Is there a way in Python to load the existing file into memory in order to speed up the calculations?

Comment: what about : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python#2888042

Comment: When using APSW, the backup API can do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could read all the tables into DataFrames with Pandas, though I'm surprised it's slow. sqlite has always been really fast for me.