# import csv into sqlite3 insert failed

Tags: csv, sqlite

I am trying to import `nodes.csv` file into sqlite3 table - [link to file](https://app.box.com/s/jdow2utngfdayj2fzzsnbemy44rlx0f2)

this is my code-

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lat REAL,
    lon REAL,
    user TEXT,
    uid INTEGER,
    version INTEGER,
    changeset INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT
);

.import nodes.csv nodes
```

I managed to import this file without the primary key designation, but once I add primary key to the id field it gives me the following error

```
nodes.csv:xxx: INSERT failed: datatype mismatch
```

for every line in the file where `xxx` is the line number. I am very new to sqlite3 and will appreciate your insights on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files contain strings. You cannot insert a string into an integer column.
(Usually, SQLite [uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY [is special](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).)

Import into a temporary table, then copy the data to the real table, while converting the numbers into actual numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes_temp(...);
.import nodes.csv nodes_temp

CREATE TABLE nodes(...);
INSERT INTO nodes
SELECT CAST(id AS INTEGER), CAST(lat AS REAL), ...
FROM nodes_temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since i am working from python pandas provides an easier way - credit to  [Tennessee Leeuwenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28802613/8980347)

```
c_nodes = "CREATE TABLE nodes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, lat REAL, lon REAL, user TEXT, uid INTEGER, \
version INTEGER, changeset INTEGER, timestamp TEXT);"

conn = sqlite3.connect('osm.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(c_nodes)
df_nodes = pd.read_csv('nodes.csv')
df_nodes.to_sql('nodes',conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```