# Create sql table from dask dataframe using map_partitions and pd.df.to_sql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dask, pandas-to-sql

Dask doesn't have a df.to_sql() like pandas and so I am trying to replicate the functionality and create an sql table using the `map_partitions` method to do so. Here is my code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy_utils as sqla_utils

db_url = 'my_db_url_connection'
conn = sqla.create_engine(db_url)

ddf = dd.read_csv('data/prod.csv')
meta=dict(ddf.dtypes)
ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.to_sql('table_name', db_url, if_exists='append',index=True), ddf, meta=meta)
```

This returns my dask dataframe object, but when I go look into my psql server there's no new table... what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE**
Still can't get it to work, but due to independent issue. Follow-up question: [duplicate key value violates unique constraint - postgres error when trying to create sql table from dask dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351783/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-postgres-error-when-trying-to-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply, you have created a dataframe which is a prescription of the work to be done, but you have not executed it. To execute, you need to call `.compute()` on the result.

Note that the output here is not really a dataframe, each partition evaluates to `None` (because `to_sql` has no output), so it might be cleaner to express this with `df.to_delayed`, something like

```
dto_sql = dask.delayed(pd.DataFrame.to_sql)
out = [dto_sql(d, 'table_name', db_url, if_exists='append', index=True)
       for d in ddf.to_delayed()]
dask.compute(*out)
```

Also note, that whether you get good parallelism will depend on the database driver and the data system itself.

Comment: Thanks for this! Your last phrase is a good point. Do you know whether postgresql would support parallelism? Is there any point in doing this at all or better just to call ddf.compute().to_sql(...)? I was hoping dask would speed things up as converting to sql is very slow, but now I see it may not be possible.

Comment: follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351783/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-postgres-error-when-trying-to-c

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** : Dask `to_sql()` is now available
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_sql

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any new solutions to this question. You should consider adding your answer as a comment to the accepted answer instead.