# Super basic python question, how to assign a dataset variable as a snowflake sql query for modeling purposes

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am a python newb (clearly) .  I just had a quick question.  How do I define a sql query as a variable?  The goal is to use this database table as the dataset for modeling purposes, but I don't know how to define the table or query as a variable syntax wise.  Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import snowflake.connector

OKTA_USER = 'username'
OKTA_PASSWORD = 'pw!'

con = snowflake.connector.connect(
 user=OKTA_USER,
 password=OKTA_PASSWORD,
 account='account',
 authenticator='account link',
)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("USE WAREHOUSE WH_GENERAL")

dataset = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There's a good answer to your "how to define the table and query" part at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888042/509840 .

Comment: Thanks, but for my purposes this would be from query not from CSV.  Maybe the process is the same, but it's hard for me to follow that guide being a novice python user.

Comment: I know you want to do a select. But you have to put data into a table before you can select anything. The link shows you how to create a table and put data into it. The example has two columns that are integers, so you should create a very simple csv with say, two integers, separated by a comma. Once you have that done, you should be able to do the select.

Comment: Just to clarify, if the database table in snowflake already exists with data, I still have to go through the same process?  I'm basically trying to select a table and then model off of it.

Comment: Also one other point is if we're talking millions of rows, there's got to be a better method, no?

Comment: ok, I think I follow. If your table already has data, then no, you don't have to create a new table and place data in it through a CSV file. I was trying to answer your question "but I don't know how to define the table or query as a variable syntax wise"

Answer (score 0):

To fetch table data into a Python data structure you can do eg:

```js
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
column_names = list(map((lambda(x) : x[0]), cur.description))
print column_names 

table  = list()
row = cur.fetchone()

while row is not None:
  table.append(row)
  row = cur.fetchone()

print table
```

The table structure will be a list of tuples, where each list element is a row and each part of the tuple is a column element.

If you want to read data into pandas, I suggest searching the internet for that.
I found this: [SQL to Pandas DataFrame](https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/) on the first try...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace part of SQL, if so we can use `replace()` function or if you have any template then you can use jinja template to format your SQL.