# searching keyword in text file and printing the entire row

Tags: python, pandas

ok so i used an api and arranged a text file that looks like this:

```
TITLE,YEAR,IMDB
'Money Plane','2000','tt7286966'
'Mulan','2020','tt4566758'
'Secret Society of Second Born Royals','2020','tt10324122'
'Train to Busan Presents: Peninsula', 'year': '2020', 'imdb_id': 'tt8850222'
'After We Collided','2020','tt10362466'
'One Night in Bangkok','2020','tt12192190'
'Phineas and Ferb The Movie: Candace Against the Universe','2020','tt1817232'
'Cats & Dogs 3: Paws Unite','2020','tt12745164'
'The Crimes That Bind','2020','tt10915060'
'Scoob!','2020','tt3152592'
'We Bare Bears: The Movie','2020','tt10474606'
'Trolls World Tour', 'year': '2020', 'imdb_id': 'tt6587640'
'Birds of Prey (and the Fantabulous Emancipation of One Harley Quinn)','2020','tt7713068'
'Bad Boys for Life','2020','tt1502397'
'Greyhound','2020','tt6048922'
'The Old Guard','2020','tt7556122'
'Sonic the Hedgehog','2020','tt3794354'
'Dad Wanted','2020','tt12721188'
'Barbie: Princess Adventure','2020','tt12767498'
```

now i want to be able so search a movie by either title,year or id

bassicaly i want to make it so that when i search for a title, it will show me the entire details about the movie,
example: search for mulan, and my output will be:

```
'Mulan','2020','tt4566758'
```

my code so far looks like this:

```
import pandas


data=pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Home\Documents\studying\newproject\moviedata.txt")
title=list(data["TITLE"])
year=list(data["YEAR"])
imdbid=list(data["IMDB"])
```

ive tried to use

```
for t,y,imdb in zip(title,year,imdbid):
   if word in title:
      items=data[word]
      print(items)
```

it runs but it does nothing

Comment: Instead of directly asking what you want, you must show what have you tried and what is the problem in your solution. [Visit Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Import the csv to SQLite (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python) and use SQL to query the data.

Comment: `df.loc[df['TITLE'].str.contains('your_key_phrase')]` will do just that. I'd recommend learning how indexing and boolean expressions work in pandas it will save you a lot of head ache :)

Comment: ok but now how do i search through the sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use here [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find value and pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to print row

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('moviedata.txt')

row , col = np.where(df == "'Mulan'")
print(df.loc[row])
```

Output:

```
    TITLE   YEAR    IMDB
1   'Mulan' '2020'  'tt4566758'
```

If you want output in form of list

```
row , col = np.where(df == "'Mulan'")
a = df.loc[row]
a = a.values.tolist()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[["'Mulan'", "'2020'", "'tt4566758'"]]
```

Comment: thats really helpfull and i didnt know you could do that with numpy

Comment: but when i do the same for the year, i get empty dataframe

Comment: @comingfall how are you passing year? Remember your all values are in single inverted commas, this should work : `row , col = np.where(df == "'2020'")`

Comment: i managed to fix that by using if statement, now im trying to insert it into a listbox. and inside the listbox its being inserted with the TITLE,YEAR,IMDBID up top. and not as a dataframe