# Compare two tsv files and save to other file but only one line is saving

Tags: python, csv

I need to compare two tsv files and save needed data to another file.

Tsv_file stands for imdb data file which contains id-rating-votes separated by tab stop and Tsv_file2 stands for my file which contais id-year separated by tab stop

All id's from tsv_file2 are in tsv_file, I need to save to zapis file data in format id-year-rating, where id from tsv_file2 matches id from tsv_file.

The problem is that code below is working but it is saving only one line into zapis file.

What can i improve to save all records?

```
for linia in read_tsv2:
    for linia2 in read_tsv:
        if linia[0] == linia2[0]:
            zapis.write(linia[0]+'\t')
            zapis.write(linia[1]+'\t')
            zapis.write(linia2[1])
```

Comment: Add a new line character to  your last line `zapis.write(linia2[1]+'\n')` to start writing to a new line after each row is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It would have made life much simpler if you had provided actual examples of these tsv files instead of describing them.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guide to ask a good question.

As I understand you have

```
 123456   4  15916
 123888   1  151687
 115945   5  35051
```

vs

```
 123456   1993
 123888   2013
```

and you want

```
 123456   1993   5
 123888   2013   1
```

There are multiple ways to cut this. I would use the SqLite function of whatever language you choose, load the data into two temp tables, and then make a query to get the data you want. It should be fairly trivial to join the two tables.

**Edit:** If the SQLite path is taken, there are plenty of good tutorials around. [Working with SQLite in Python](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/),   [How to import a CSV in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python) (with Python).

I would do the following, in broad terms:

- create a :memory: database in SQLite
- create tables

(these steps can be omitted, and a database +table can be created by an SQLite editor in advance)

- connect to DB
- import each TSV file into a table
- execute a query on the database
- output the result

Python should have libraries for most of these tasks.

The exact same result can be done with other tools.

Comment: @dronikk if it is helping you suggest to mark helpful or solved.