# python sqlite3 uploading data to DB from excel(xls/xlsx)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a DB from an excel spreadsheet. I can fetch data from excel and display in the html page, but I am not able to store it in sqlite db.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to review [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show code and results so far in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ways you can try:

1. Save excel as csv. Read csv in python ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) and save in sqlite ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888042)).
2. Read excel into a pandas dataframe ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)), and then save dataframe to sqlite ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)).
3. Read excel directly from python ([link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)) and save data to sqlite.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code which worked but it over rights file.

#import pandas software library
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\kmc487\PycharmProjects\myproject\Product List.xlsx')

#Print sheet1
print(df)

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet_1")

Below are the input file details:

1. My input file is in .xlsx format and file is stored as .xls(Need code to .xlsx format)
2. File has heading in second row(First row blank)