# Python 3: Performing "left join" of two lists of lists without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

Due to a restriction on being able to use pandas (not allowed) I am trying to do a left join operation between two csv files.  I'm struggling.  Here is an example:

```
import csv

def read_csv(path):
    file = open(path, "r")
    content_list = []    
    for line in file.readlines():
        record = line.split(",")
        for item in range(len(record)):
            record[item] = record[item].replace("\n","")    
        content_list.append(tuple(record))
    return content_list 

lookup_list = read_csv("lookup.csv")
data_list = read_csv("data.csv")

print("list with id and name:")
print(lookup_list)
print("list with id, age, weight:")
print(data_list)

result =list()
data_dict = {x[0]: x for x in data_list[1:]}

for left in lookup_list[1:]:
    if left[0] in data_dict:
        result.append(data_dict.get(left[0]) + left[1:])

print("Result of merge:")
print(result)
```

> > > 

**list with id and name:**

[('id', 'name'), ('123', 'Robin'), ('221', 'Larry'), ('331', 'Wilson'), ('412', 'Jack')]

**list with id, age, weight:**

[('id', 'age', 'weight'), ('123', '47', '320'), ('221', '47', '190'), ('331', '25', '225'), ('412', '21', '180'), ('110', '14', '150')]

**Result of merge:**

[('123', '47', '320', 'Robin'), ('221', '47', '190', 'Larry'), ('331', '25', '225', 'Wilson'), ('412', '21', '180', 'Jack')]

As the lookup_list does not have an entry for id 110, it is not included in the results.  I need it to be included in the results with an empty value for 'name'.  This is where I'm struggling.

This was so much easier with pandas but our automation engineers are restricting us to only libraries/modules included with the standard python distribution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have `if left[0] in data_dict`, which is a good start. What about if that's not true? An `else` clause perhaps? Also, bummer about your automation folks -- wasting time on this when there's a library that solves it really well is probably not a great use of y'all's resources.

Comment: The easy way to do this is to convert both your CSV files to dictionaries with ID as the key.  That lets you avoid the lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does as I described, and reads the lists into dictionaries.  You can then write a new CSV file with the combined results.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

def read_csv(path):
    file = open(path, "r")
    contents = {}
    header = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        record = line.strip().split(",")
        if not header:
            header = record
        else:
            contents[record[0]] = {a:b for a,b in zip(header,record)}
    return contents

lookup_list = read_csv("xxx.csv")
data_list = read_csv("yyy.csv")

print("list with id and name:")
pprint(lookup_list)
print("list with id, age, weight:")
pprint(data_list)

for k,v in data_list.items():
    if k not in lookup_list:
        lookup_list[k] = {'name':''}
    lookup_list[k].update(v)

print("Result of merge:")
pprint(lookup_list)
```

Output:

```
list with id and name:
{'123': {'id': '123', 'name': 'Robin'},
 '221': {'id': '221', 'name': 'Larry'},
 '331': {'id': '331', 'name': 'Wilson'},
 '412': {'id': '412', 'name': 'Jack'}}
list with id, age, weight:
{'110': {'age': '14', 'id': '110', 'weight': '150'},
 '123': {'age': '47', 'id': '123', 'weight': '320'},
 '221': {'age': '47', 'id': '221', 'weight': '190'},
 '331': {'age': '25', 'id': '331', 'weight': '255'},
 '412': {'age': '21', 'id': '412', 'weight': '180'}}
Result of merge:
{'110': {'age': '14', 'id': '110', 'name': '', 'weight': '150'},
 '123': {'age': '47', 'id': '123', 'name': 'Robin', 'weight': '320'},
 '221': {'age': '47', 'id': '221', 'name': 'Larry', 'weight': '190'},
 '331': {'age': '25', 'id': '331', 'name': 'Wilson', 'weight': '255'},
 '412': {'age': '21', 'id': '412', 'name': 'Jack', 'weight': '180'}}
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Just to further the discussion, here's how it would be done in sqlite.  I suppose each individual needs to evaluate whether this is better or not.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.execute( 'CREATE TABLE lookup (id int, name text);' )
db.execute( 'CREATE TABLE data (id int, age int, weight int);' )

def read_csv(db, table, path):
    cur = db.cursor()
    header = []
    for line in open(path).readlines():
        if not header:
            header = line.rstrip()
            continue
        record = line.strip().split(",")
        sql = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({header}) VALUES ("
        sql += ','.join(['?']*len(record)) + ");"
        cur.execute(sql, record)

lookup_list = read_csv(db, "lookup", "xxx.csv")
data_list = read_csv(db, "data", "yyy.csv")

cur = db.cursor()
for row in cur.execute(
    "SELECT data.id,lookup.name,data.age,data.weight FROM data LEFT JOIN lookup ON lookup.id = data.id;"):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
(123, 'Robin', 47, 320)
(221, 'Larry', 47, 190)
(331, 'Wilson', 25, 255)
(412, 'Jack', 21, 180)
(110, None, 14, 150)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  This does precisely what I needed.  And with the dictionary it'll be easy enough to output to csv or json.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3` is included with the standard Python distribution.

You can just create an in-memory database, put the csv contents into tables, and do an actual left join.

See this answer for creating an sqlite database from csv
[Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python)

create your tables using the method shown in that answer.  Let's say you have called your tables `t_lookup` and `t_data`, and your database connection is called `conn1`.

```
cursor = conn1.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM
t_data t1
LEFT JOIN
t_lookup t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;''')

left_result = cursor.fetchall()

for row in left_result:
    print(row)

conn1.close()
```

Comment: This is not good advice.  Sqlite doesn't add anything that isn't already available in dictionaries.  And an answer should always include code to demonstrate your suggestion.  What you have here is little more than a comment.

Comment: Disagree, because the question specifically asks about left joins and not having access to Pandas.  It is much more intuitive to do a left join with SQL than to use dictionaries.  Also sqlite3 adds access to every statement, function, etc. in sqlite.  This is much more than is available with dictionaries.

Comment: @TimRoberts disagree with the first point, as sqlite is more powerful and can handle edge cases. and agrees with a second one that it's more like a comment, SO does not allow to put a comment before 100 or so reputation. it is great alternative i feel.

Comment: Totally true. Sqlite is a nice point on the topic

Comment: You have the tables in your join backwards.  `t_data` is the master, `t_lookup` is the one that might have missing rows.  That's why posting a complete, runnable script is important.

Comment: if that is the case then you would just switch t_lookup and t_data in the execute statement.  The point remains the same; this is another approach.